# Importing Delphi Dll Into My Vb.net Project

Tags: vb.net, delphi, interop

i tried to import delphi dll into my vb.net project

this is my code:

```
Private Declare Function AddIntegers Lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\first dll\Project2.dll" Alias "AddIntegers" (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ii As Integer = AddIntegers(1, 3)
        MsgBox(ii)
    End Sub
```

this is the delphi library code:

```
library MyFirstLibrary;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes;

{$R *.res}

function AddIntegers(_a, _b: integer): integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := _a + _b;
end;

exports
   AddIntegers;
begin
end.
```

there is an EntryPointNotFoundException:

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'AddIntegers' in DLL 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\first dll\Project2.dll'.":""
```

how can i fix the EntryPointNotFoundException(the function AddIntegers is exist in my delphi code)?
(vb.net or c#)

Comment: Why did you remove your previous question?

Comment: Because I thought that I solved it.

Comment: wouldn't you then think it would make sense to have answered your own question, accepted the answer, and left it there for users encountering the same problem?

Comment: I did not think about it at the moment,Learning from mistakes

Comment: Can you attach dll somewhere to see the list of exported functions?

Comment: i cant see the exported functions

Comment: Can you see them with dependency walker or with `dumpbin /exports`?

Comment: Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Comment: @Burgos, the function is exported. That's the part of the Delphi library called `exports`. The problem is on the .NET side. Maybe you were right with your answer. Just change the calling convention. By default is `stdcall`, isn't it ?

Comment: @TLama, let's see. Default is stdcall, as I recall.

Comment: @Burgos when i click on PROJECT2.DLL on the dependency walker there is no functions, Could be that the problem is in the delphi library code?

Comment: It seems to be the problem. Try writing it like this:

`function AddIntegers(_a, _b: integer): integer; export;`

Comment: i still cant see the function :/ maybe the problem is the delphi version? (im using delphi 6)

Comment: No, the Delphi part is fine!

Comment: If the Delphi part is fine, why can't he see exports in Dependency Walker?

Comment: Again, can you attach that dll, as I've been reading all over the internet for an hour or so to find what is wrong?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\first dll\Project2.dll" is exist.

Comment: @jSS, ok, it might exist. But is that `Project2.dll` library built from the Delphi code you've posted (except the first line) ? Are you importing the right *.dll ? I don't know what your `Project2.dll` library does. You should know. Try to [start from the beginning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672090/importing-delphi-dll-into-my-vb-net-project#comment20510102_14672157).

Comment: i tried :/ still same result.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but I'm giving up. I've tested this using the Delphi library code you've posted here with a VB code from my post. It worked for me...

Comment: For the love of god, use a debugging tool. The message is clear. There is not export of that name. Load the DLL in Dependency Walker. See what functions are exported. See why your one is not/

Comment: You are creating `library MyFirstLibrary` (with `{$R *.res}`) but your output DLL is `Project2.dll`? not `MyFirstLibrary.dll`? does this even compile? I suspect this is not your real code. I suggest you start fresh with a new project, at a new directory (and don't use hard coded paths). this is really too localized.   @Burgos, `export` have no effect in 32-bit DLL.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, the only way this could happen is if you are either not importing the right DLL. User error, not Delphi or VB error.

Comment: It could also be as simple as you've compiled the DLL once, then you added the code, and never bothered to re-compile it again so the DLL is still running the old code. If you've corrected your mis-match of library names, then this is your only other possibility.

Comment: @jSS, have you resolved this somehow ?

Comment: @TLama No, i tried every answer, still no success.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you're loading a different library. You're loading the `Project2.dll`, while your Delphi library is called `MyFirstLibrary.dll` in code you've posted in your question.

Comment: Same result (EntryPointNotFoundException)

Comment: See the update. I think that you're loading a different library. But anyway, it's a bad idea to hardcode paths this way.

Comment: You must mess with a different library. Some, which has a different export of the function you're trying to import here. Try to make a brand new Delphi library using the code you have, save that Delphi project with a new (unique) name, build it and the path to that brand new library enter to the `<DllImport>` clause with the exact path.

Comment: The presence of code in this answer seems rather pointless. It seems obvious that the actual problem is that the VB code is loading a different library from the code in the question. There's a glaring mismatch between the name of the DLL specified in the managed code and the name of the `library` specified in the native code. Doesn't matter whether you use `Declare` or `DllImport`. That's just not the problem at all.

Comment: @David, feel free to write your own answer. I was going to delete this one anyway... I didn't knew about `Declare`, but there's really no difference.

Comment: I don't want to write an answer. The answer is simply your first paragraph. That's all that's needed. And I upvoted because of that. The code just dilutes the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with `DllImport` directly and applying different calling convention modifier:

```
<DllImport("C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\Delphi6\Projects\first dll\Project2.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Private Shared Function AddIntegers(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
```

Comment: You have used wrong calling convention, don't you ? Here OP uses `stdcall`...

Comment: That's still wrong. You're explicitly saying you want to use `Cdecl`.

Comment: I've changed it into stdcall - sorry! But, that should be default on Windows system, per MSDN.. I am staring to think that there could be prefix in the dlls entry point or something like this - otherwise, it should work.

Comment: That's better, but now the only difference between our answers is that you've hardcoded the path to the library, while I'm expecting it to be visible to the assembly. Default calling convention for P/Invoke is `stdcall`, so even if you omit that `CallingConvention` part, it will do the same.

Comment: @TLama In fact there's no real difference between the code in the two answers and that in the question.